# CakePHP Migrations Plugin Workflow

Tags: mysql, cakephp, migration

Where I work we use this plugin to manage our database changes. Lately the people who deploy our projects have been having issues using the plugin because they are being run on databases that contain data already.

For instance, when adding a field to an already existing table that is going to be a foreign key and can not be null there are usually problems if there is already data in the production environment for that particular table. Running the migrations from start to finish from an empty database pretty much always works but when there is data it seems iffy at best.

Most of the workflow examples I have seen floating around on the internet show it being used during development and not for deployment. The only thing I can think is happening here is that the people collaborating are dumping the data in their own tables before they run the migrations.

Of course I am asking for a workflow example here so I shouldn't assume. Just kind of confused as to what good this is if you are working with an environment that has data that you don't want to lose?

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well I am not sure why are you facing issues here. We have been working with this plugin to manage our deployments and it has been smooth enough on all servers we deploy on (with millions of records).

I just checked to make sure this case happened through any of our migrations and found it there a couple of times without any issues ! Here's a copy of one of them and that ran smoothly and added the new field.

```
   'create_field' => array(
        'TableName' => array(
            'fieldName' => array('type' => 'integer', 'null' => false, 'default' => NULL)
        ),
    ),
```

Comment: What database system are you using if it is alright to ask?

Comment: Sure, It's a MySql database (V5.5)